# ibm mobile first development server .. run as options missing sometimes.. unable to start application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Build and deploy settings are missing from ibm mobile first development server hybrid project.
After clicking on Run as(as in attachment) even from a newly created project..not finding any options. Unable to start application.
Please let me know why it is happening, if any have faced this error before. The image below shows that there's nothing in "Run As...".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your installation.

Try again in a new Eclipse workspace.
If it fails as well, re-install the Studio plug-in in a fresh Eclipse instance.

Comment: ya this issue resolved .. did as suggested .. thanks